# On click button color change action in Google Apps Script, Gmail API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am using CardService provided by Google Apps Script and creating a card for Gmail Add-On. I create a card and include a button as a widget. However, I want when that button is clicked, its color should change. I know I can use SetBackgroundColor method (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setBackgroundColor(String)) however, I am not sure if I will have to create a new card and update it in order to show the color change of button or how should I achieve this front end functionality?

```
function createCard(){
  var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection()
  var newAction = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('changeButtonColor')
  var button = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Hello').setOnClickAction(newAction)
  cardSection.addWidget(button)
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder().setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('How To Change Button Color as an On Click Action')).addSection(cardSection).build()
  return card
}

function changeButtonColor(){
  //TODO
  //Update the card with changed button color
}
```

That's how I think it should be done. But I dont want to update the card for each click of a button. Is there any other way to get the change of the button's color?

Comment: You'll have to rebuild/update the card. CardService follows a stateless model, where once you build a card changing the elements you used to build it (in this case the color of a button) won't affect a card that's already been rendered. You'll have to figure out how to track and manage state yourself and re-render your cards accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you for the reply.
I have 2 additional questions, if you could help. 
1) Do you if there is any way to show a pop-up using CardService? I saw there is an enum, OverLay but I think it is just for opening URLs and not for customised other pop-ups. Is my knowledge correct? Also, if you could suggest any way to create a pop-up.
2) If I have a button which enables me to move my email from inbox to a label then I have to refresh to see its effect. How can I refresh/ reload my inbox which clicking on the button itself. 
Thanks in advance.